# Django model formset cannot be saved

Tags: django

I have a web page include a job request and inlinformset for the possible candidates with a button to set an interview which works fine. For each candidate, there should be one Interview or more for the same job request. when the user click on interview button he will be transfered to another page for the interviews with URL Para for the job requisition id (jid) and candidate id (cid), as the follwoing

```
class InterviewForm(ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Interview 
    exclude = ()

InterviewFormSet = modelformset_factory(Interview,form=InterviewForm, extra=1)
```

Interview Model

```
class Interview(models.Model): 
  jobRequisition = models.ForeignKey(JobRequisition, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
  interviewer = models.ManyToManyField(Employee) 
  candidate = models.ForeignKey(Candidate, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
  interview_date =  models.DateField( blank = True)
  interview_type = models.CharField(max_length=150, choices= interview_type )
```

view:

```
class InterviewCreate(CreateView):
  model =  Interview
  form_class = InterviewForm
  success_url = reverse_lazy('jobRequisitions-list') 

  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    # bring all interviews related to the selected candidate and job request
    qu = Interview.objects.filter(jobRequisition=self.kwargs['jid'], candidate=self.kwargs['cid'])
    context = super(InterviewCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    if self.request.POST:
        context['candidateinterviews'] = InterviewFormSet(self.request.POST)
    else:
        context['candidateinterviews'] = InterviewFormSet(queryset=qu)
    return context
```

My issues:
1- cannot save: when I click on save button, I get some error to fill in the missing data, so, the validation is working well, but after that, I couldn't save the data in the formset. I have tried to use "def form_valid(self, form): print("I'm here")" but it seems the code doesn't enter this function and it always got to the form_invalid.

[image]

2- Default values from url para: I want to hide the candidate name and job requisition number from the user, and when he click save, those data will be extracted automatically from the url and get saved with the other entries. I can get the para from url but I couldn't append them to the formst and get them saved to the database.

The updated View:

```
def InterviewCreate(request, jid, cid):
  jobRequisitions_url = '/recruitment_single_company/jobRequisitions/' + str(jid)   
  if request.method == "POST":
    candidateinterviews = InterviewFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES) 
    if(candidateinterviews.is_valid()):
        candidateinterviews.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(jobRequisitions_url)    
    else:
        print ("Something went wrong"   )
  else:
    candidateinterviews = InterviewFormSet(queryset=Interview.objects.filter(jobRequisition=jid, candidate=cid))
  return render(request, 'recruitment_single_company/interview_form.html', {'formset': candidateinterviews})
```

so far the code is wroking as long as I entered the job request_id and candidate_id manually, but I want to hide both fileds and save them whenever the form is valid.
I have tried to replace the line before last in the above code and added the initial data (as shown below) and it worked, but when I want to hide both fieldes using "exclude" I couldn't save the form. Can I hide the fields witout excluding them?

```
candidateinterviews = InterviewFormSet(queryset=Interview.objects.filter(jobRequisition=jid, candidate=cid), initial=[{'jobRequisition': jid, 'candidate': cid,}])
```

Comment: A `CreateView` is meant for creating a single instance, it doesn't make sense to use it with a formset like this. I suggest you use a function-based view, or look at [django-extra-views`](https://github.com/AndrewIngram/django-extra-views)

Comment: Thank you Alasdair, your comment solved my first issue. Do you know how to solve the second question using function-based view

Comment: It’s harder to answer your question when you don’t show the view

Comment: Thank you, I solved the problem and updated my question for anyone need it.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. It's better to add your solution as an answer. That way you can mark it as accepted, and it's clear that your problem has been solved.

Comment: Done, as recommended. Thank you I have used many of your answers for other issues in stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is my final view, and I'm using [jquery.formset.js](https://github.com/elo80ka/django-dynamic-formset)

```
def InterviewCreate(request, jid, cid):
  jobRequisitions_url = '/recruitment_single_company/jobRequisitions/' + str(jid)   

  if "cancel_btn" in request.POST: # if user click cancel/back button then it will go to previous page
    return HttpResponseRedirect(jobRequisitions_url) 

  if request.method == "POST":
    candidateinterviews = InterviewFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES) 
    if candidateinterviews.is_valid() and candidateinterviews.has_changed():
        for form in candidateinterviews:
            interview_date = form.cleaned_data.get('interview_date')
            if form.cleaned_data.get('DELETE') and form.cleaned_data.get('id') != None:
                interview_id = form.cleaned_data.get('id').id
                Interview.objects.filter(id=interview_id).delete()
            # Belw is my way to do extra validation, without it Django will try to save data
            # even if there is no change and it will give the below error:
            # The Interview could not be created because the data didn't validate.     
            elif interview_date != None:
                obj = form.save(commit=False) # we need this because we have excluded fields in the form
                obj.jobRequisition_id = jid # manually save the foreign key for job requestion
                obj.candidate_id = cid # manually save the foreign key for candidate
                obj.save()
                form.save_m2m() # we need this since we have many to many fields
    else:
        candidateinterviews = InterviewFormSet(queryset=Interview.objects.filter(jobRequisition=jid, candidate=cid))
  else:
    candidateinterviews = InterviewFormSet(queryset=Interview.objects.filter(jobRequisition=jid, candidate=cid))

  return render(request, 'recruitment_single_company/interview_form.html', {'candidateinterviews': candidateinterviews})
```

also, I have updated InterviewForm to hide two columns

```
class InterviewForm(ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Interview 
    exclude = (['jobRequisition', 'candidate'] )

InterviewFormSet = modelformset_factory(Interview, form=InterviewForm, extra=1, can_delete=True)
```